# crystal report in specific format

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am working on a report haveing data like below

```
id  Item    Brand   Size        Area    Rate    Amount  height  width   Material    image
3   item1   Brand1  100 x 200   2.44    20      20      100     200     Material1   Image1
3   item2   Brand2  100 x 200   1       30      30      100     200     Material2   Image1
3   item3   Brand3  100 x 200   1       40      40      100     200     Material3   Image1
4   item1   Brand1  100 x 200   2.44    15      15      100     200     Material1   Image2
4   item2   Brand2  100 x 200   1       30      30      100     200     Material2   Image2
4   item3   Brand3  100 x 200   1       45      45      100     200     Material3   Image2
```

In Report i have to show the image on top, data in table below for id 3, on next page image2 and data with id 4. this is a long list like this.

I can show image dynamically in the report, but the problem is grouping and format.I am doing it using dataset in asp.net. Any suggestion or guidance ? I have spent several hours but not figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a group by id column.

Then, in the group header, show the image.

In detail session, show the rest of the data.

Finally, tell the group header to "new page before" if group number > 1.